# Error orchestrating web service deployed in azure with Apache ODE

Tags: azure, xsd, wsdl, bpel, apache-ode

I am trying to orchestrate a web service deployed in Windows Azure with Apache ODE. I am testing the services with the Eclipse integrated Web Service Explorer. The Azure WS works fine but when I test the Artifacts.wsdl it throws the following error:

```
14:41:38,777 INFO  [DeploymentPoller] Deployment of artifact BPEL_process successful: [{http://artifacts}process-132]
14:41:49,474 WARN  [SimpleScheduler] Dispatching jobs with more than 5 minutes delay. Either the server was down for some time or the job load is greater than available capacity
14:41:57,594 WARN  [ExternalService] Fault response: faultType=(unkown)
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the &lt;serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
14:41:57,620 ERROR [INVOKE] Failure during invoke: 
14:41:57,623 INFO  [BpelRuntimeContextImpl] ActivityRecovery: Registering activity 15, failure reason:  on channel 27
```

Here are the files:

[process.bpel](http://pastebin.com/0JiGjKR0)

[Artifacts.wsdl](http://pastebin.com/aSZEJujE)

[mod2.wsdl](http://pastebin.com/7SEZXDim)

[mod2.xsd](http://pastebin.com/xNMDi7Rx)

**EDIT** This is what I get when I add the `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` in my Web Service:

```
17:51:49,762 WARN  [ExternalService] Fault response: faultType=(unkown)
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</faultstring><detail><axis2ns1:ExceptionDetail xmlns:axis2ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><axis2ns1:HelpLink i:nil="true" /><axis2ns1:InnerException i:nil="true" /><axis2ns1:Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</axis2ns1:Message><axis2ns1:StackTrace>   at WCFServiceWebRole1.AzureImpl.mod2(String arg0)&#xd;
   at SyncInvokemod2(Object , Object[] , Object[] )&#xd;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)&#xd;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xd;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xd;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xd;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</axis2ns1:StackTrace><axis2ns1:Type>System.NullReferenceException</axis2ns1:Type></axis2ns1:ExceptionDetail></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
17:51:49,798 ERROR [INVOKE] Failure during invoke: 
17:51:49,801 INFO  [BpelRuntimeContextImpl] ActivityRecovery: Registering activity 15, failure reason:  on channel 27
```

Still no clue of what it means. Eclipse points out en error on my bpel file. The `<copy>` tag under `<assign>` throws:

`The from-spec of "<xs:simpleType "string">" is not compatible with to-spec of "<xs:complexType>"` but I ignored it because following the xsd schemas it doesn't make sense to me and sometimes it even disappears.

**EDIT II:**

As mentioned by @vanto the `<assign>` activity was wrong. I had to add the prefix of the namespace of my wsdl to the CDATA tag:

```
<bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
  <![CDATA[mod2:mod2Result]]>
</bpel:query>
```

Still don't fully understantand namespaces but it seems it is related to the fact I had to add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the xsd imported by the wsdl of the Azure Service.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that ODE got a soap fault as a response. This indicates that the invoked Web service raised an exception. Please check the logs of your web service or turn on the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults feature in order to get details about what went wrong. Please not that ODE does not validate outgoing messages, so if your `<assign>` activities do not create the correct request, ODE won't notice but the invoked service is likely to complain.

Comment: Thanks @vanto, I have added the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults to my WS but still no clue. Look at the edited question please.